# Is there a way to install Laravel offline just like CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, laravel

I am studying Laravel as my 2nd framework. Before I am using CodeIgniter and after switching to Laravel it looks so difficult. I already tried to install laravel using composer but it is online. I just want to ask if there is a way that I can install a fresh copy of laravel offline? Just like in CodeIgniter. You just unzip the file and that's it. Here's my folder structure:

```
/wamp
  /www
      /laravel --- main laravel code
      /sample_laravel --- this is the installation using online
      /blog --- this is a blank folder, it is the folder I want to install my laravel
```

In online I tried to use this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel sample_laravel --prefer-dist
```

And it is ok. Can I do this even I don't have internet connection? Because I thinks it requires an active connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I do this even I don't have internet connection?

No. The whole point of using Composer is to pull your dependencies from online repositories. You need an internet connection to run Composer.

[This link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip) will download a zip of the latest Master which is taken directly from the main Laravel Github account.

Comment: Ok. I just donwloaded it and can I just copy and paste this whole folder into another PC? And change the folder name for my desired name.  So you mean that using Composer is just like updating the files to their repository?

Comment: I really suggest [reading up on Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) before you dive in. You'll save yourself a lot of frustration when you understand what Composer is aimed to accomplish. Composer in a nutshell gives developers a dead-easy repository management system for projects. It takes the legwork out of individually managing libraries. To answer your question about where to place the contents of the .zip file, yes you place that where whatever localhost you are using can see & serve the files.

Comment: Ok thanks again for the help. I am really a beginner with this. :)

Comment: No problem! Just do yourself a favor: slow down a bit, read up on `what` you're doing and `why` and then experiment.